# What is `using a = Func<>;` syntax in C#?

Tags: c#

What is the name of this syntax? How can I use it?

```
using AppFunc = Func<IDictionary<string, object>, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>;
public class A
{
}
```

Comment: @user3596113 maybe I don't know any thing about it..

Comment: You could always [look it up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`using` normally used to import namespace to use in that file

But it could be used to make an alias to shorten a long or complicate type with that syntax

For example

```
using Dict = Dictionary<string,string>
```

When you call

```
Dict dict = new Dict();
```

at compile time it will be convert to

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>()
```

It just syntactic sugar like #DEFINE in C++

Comment: Actually more like typedef or C++11 using.